# sql to fetch column names as string depending on row values

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with data in below format

```
custid  scr1    scr2    scr3
1111    1       2       3
2222    4       3       2
3333    4       5       3
```

I need to pick column names per custid, sorted by row values like below

```
custid  str
1111    scr3,scr2,scr1
2222    scr1,scr2,scr3
3333    scr2,scr1,scr3
```

What is the best way to achieve this

Comment: mysql or hive..?

Comment: primarily looking for hive solution .

Comment: can you have more columns or only the 3 shown?

Comment: only the 3 shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  custid
       ,concat_ws
        (
            ','
           ,max (case when rn = 1 then col end)
           ,max (case when rn = 2 then col end)
           ,max (case when rn = 3 then col end)
        ) as str

from   (select  custid
               ,elt (pe.pos+1,'scr1','scr2','scr3') as col

               ,row_number () over 
                (
                    partition by    t.custid
                    order by        pe.val desc
                ) rn               

        from    mytable t lateral view posexplode (array (scr1,scr2,scr3)) pe
        ) t

group by    t.custid
```

---

```
+--------+----------------+
| custid |      str       |
+--------+----------------+
|   1111 | scr3,scr2,scr1 |
|   2222 | scr1,scr2,scr3 |
|   3333 | scr2,scr1,scr3 |
+--------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred solution

```
select  custid
       ,concat_ws (',',scr[0].col2,scr[1].col2,scr[2].col2)     as str

from   (select  custid

               ,sort_array
                (
                    array
                    (
                        struct(-scr1,'scr1')
                       ,struct(-scr2,'scr2')
                       ,struct(-scr3,'scr3')
                    )
                ) as scr

        from    mytable
        ) t
```

---

```
+--------+----------------+
| custid |      str       |
+--------+----------------+
|   1111 | scr3,scr2,scr1 |
|   2222 | scr1,scr2,scr3 |
|   3333 | scr2,scr1,scr3 |
+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: Argument type mismatch ''scr3'': Argument 1 of function SORT_ARRAY must be array<PRIMITIVE>, but array<struct<col1:double,col2:string>> was found.

Comment: This is a tested code (The earliest version I've tested is Hive 1.1.0). What Hive version are you using?

Comment: hive 2.3 . my create table query is  create table mytable as  select '1111' as custid,'1' as scr1,'2' as scr2,'3' as scr3 union select '2222','4','3','2' union select '3333','4','5','3'

Comment: weirdly, it complains of first argument being double. describe table gives ..
custid                  string
scr1                    string
scr2                    string
scr3                    string

Comment: There is no such version and apparently is should be less than 1.1.0

Comment: Hive 1.2.1.2.3.4.78-6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144391/discussion-between-mhn-and-dudu-markovitz).

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. Please run `hive --version` from  bash

Answer (score 1):

One more approach is unpivoting the table data using `union all` and assigning row numbers based on scr1,scr2,scr3 values. Then aggregate by custid to generate csv values.

```
with rownums as 
(select t.*,row_number() over(partition by custid order by cast(scr as int) desc) as rnum 
 from (select custid,scr1 as scr,'scr1' as col from mytable
       union all
       select custid,scr2 as scr,'scr2' as col from mytable
       union all
       select custid,scr3 as scr,'scr3' as col from mytable
      ) t    
)
select custid,concat(max(case when rnum=1 then col end),',',max(case when rnum=2 then col end),',',max(case when rnum=3 then col end))
from rownums
group by custid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Step1. Unpivot the initial query set into BASEQ first

BASEQ:

```
    select * from UT_TEST
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                SCRVAL for SCRNAME in (
                scr1 as 'scr1',
                scr2 as 'scr2',
                scr3 as 'scr3'
            )
        )
```

Resultset:

```
        1111    scr1    1
        1111    scr2    2
        1111    scr3    3
        2222    scr1    4
        2222    scr2    3
        2222    scr3    2
        3333    scr1    4
        3333    scr2    5
        3333    scr3    3
```

Step2: Then use LISTAGG

Here is the code

```
    WITH BASEQ
    AS
    (
        select * from UT_TEST
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                SCRVAL for SCRNAME in (
                scr1 as 'scr1',
                scr2 as 'scr2',
                scr3 as 'scr3'
            )
        )
    )
    SELECT BASEQ.CUSTID, LISTAGG(BASEQ.SCRNAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BASEQ.SCRVAL DESC) FINALCOL FROM BASEQ
    GROUP BY BASEQ.CUSTID;
```

Final Resultset:

```
        1111    scr3,scr2,scr1
        2222    scr1,scr2,scr3
        3333    scr2,scr1,scr3
```

Comment: Have you seen the `hive` tag?

Comment: I thought so. Since the answer is not relevant, please delete it.